# How can I get the output of Cloudfoudry CLI vmc/cf by "grep"

Tags: grep, cloud-foundry, vmc

I have used the following command

```
vmc info |grep target
```

I can get the target info exactly. But when I type:

```
vmc apps  |grep running
```

There is no output.
If I try to redirect the stdout to file like:

```
vmc apps &> tmplog
```

I was confused to see that only the first column of the output (appname) was written into the file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It may be the case that you need to redirect both unix output streams to see the complete log. There is STDOUT (1) and STDERR (2). To redirect both streams to the same file by using

```
vmc apps > tmplog 2 &> tmplog
```

Your last line above only redirected one output stream (STDOUT). The other stream may be written to to console instead.

Additionally, the `vmc` CLI is pretty much outdated. For the current go implementation of the CF CLI (`gcf`/`cf`), I successfully tested the following command to work

```
cf logs $YOUR_APP_NAME | grep RTR
```